# How can i show the first published demands in Symfony2 ?

Tags: php, symfony

I need just to show the first published demands:

```
$demand = $em->getRepository('DemandsBundle:Demands')->findBy(array('date' => )?
```

I have a problem in this request, can someone tell me how can I make :`findby` to just replay the first demand in my database?

in controller :

`$entity->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));`

in Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $createdAt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $query = $em->createQuery(
 'SELECT p.content , p.createdAt , p.id
 FROM PublishDemandsBundle:Demands p

 ORDER BY p.createdAt 

 '
);

$demands = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can order the results by `date asc` passing it to findBy function as 2nd parameter, then take the first row setting the `limit` as 3rd parameter.

here is the definition for the `findBy` function

`public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null);`

here is the example for your case:

```
$demand = $em->getRepository('DemandsBundle:Demands')->findBy(array(), array('date' => 'asc'), 1);
```

**Otherwise**

you can also use `findOneBy` function where you can also skip the `limit` parameter since it returns only one result.

`public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null);`

little example:

```
$demand = $em->getRepository('DemandsBundle:Demands')->findOneBy(array(), array('date' => 'asc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findOneBy` instead of `findBy`